# How to perform shell "for" command over files with spaces in names?

Tags: bash, command-line, shell, find

I find myself frequently doing the following:

```
for f in `find -foo -bar -baz`; do
  process "$f"
done
```

This of course doesn't work for file names with spaces. How can I handle such cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f | while read file; do 
     process "$f"
done;
```

Comment: "$f" should be "$file". Use `while read -r` to take of literal backslash in file names

Answer (score 4):

Find and xargs work well together. find can print the names of the files with a `\0`-delimiter (option `print0`) and xargs can read them in that format (option `-0`):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

Comment: Don't forget xargs! On lists of very large numbers of files, you may find yourself getting the dreaded "Too many arguments" error. These two O'Reilly articles explain the situation: http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/lpt/09_21.html http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/lpt/09_22.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are using find already, why not simply use exec

```
find -foo -bar -baz -exec process '{}' \;
```

The alternative solution would be to change the IFS variable (inter field seperator)

Answer (score 1):

bash 4

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in /path/**
do
  process "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, my approach is to build the list before the `for` command and replace whitespace inside element names by another character or string which is unlikely to appear.

Then inside the loop, I replace back that specific string by a whitespace.

An example:

```
list=`find -foo -bar -baz | tr ' ' 'µ'`
for fx in $list ; do
    f=`echo $fx | tr 'µ' ' '`
    process "$f"
done
```

Comment: This is verbose and not robust.